# Is there a way to load xml files dynamic more than 5000 fast in spring boot?

Tags: xml, spring, dynamic

in my spring boot application, i have to load xml files dynamic more than 5000 at the application startup. now, xmls can be load successful and run it correct. but the startup process spend time more than 20min. the step as belowe:

1. loadBeanDefinitions xml source using xmlBeanDefinitionReader.
2. refresh spring context. (spend much time)

So, can you give me some suggestions to help me reduce the startup time of my application?

i want to reduce the startup time of my application.

Comment: why do you have 5000 XML files that you need to load at startup? Sounds like you should fix that poor design rather then try to work around it tbh.

Comment: in my application, all implementation of the business logic are using spring integration flow. eg, there is a integration flow to "create user", then the first block is ''check user exists", and the second block is "insert user". and there has much flow as this.

Comment: XML configuration is the old way of doing it. Modern way is through DSL and lazy initialization.

Comment: If you are stuck with XML configuration, why do you have 5000 files? You can combine them. You shouldn't have one per file.